# Textbox to fill space

Tags: html, css, css-float

Consider the following.

2 DIVS - the left one of known width, the right one of unknown width.

We can make the right-hand side fill the remaining space, however if I exchange the right-hand DIV to a textbox, it then does not fill the space, but wraps below the left-hand div.

Here's a fiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/1506/)

```
<div>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <input type="textbox" id="right">
        right
    </input>
</div>

#left {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

I'm confused - any advice?

Still not behaving as it should!

New fiddle here: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/1517/)

Comment: DIVs are a display type of 'block' whereas controls are 'inline'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/MHeqG/1508/)**
Inputs are inline bydefault and only the
Block level elements can aquire the remaining space left after a floating element. So you should change the `display` property for input to `block` i.e. `display:block`

```css
 #left {
     float:left;
     width:180px;
     background-color:#ff0000;
 }
 #right {  
     display:block;
     background-color:#00FF00;
 }
```

```html
 <div>
     <div id="left">
         left
     </div>
     <input type="textbox" value="right" id="right"/>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**  http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/MHeqG/1522/ using Calc.

Comment: Yes, that works great for me - you learn something new every day. Thanks.

Comment: We'll get ya to 3000 :P

Comment: @NaeemShaikh - I've been trying the solution out in the proper environment - added another couple of code snippets - odd behaviour which also breaks your solution. http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/1517/

Comment: @dotnetnoob http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/MHeqG/1522/ you can use calc for your code..

Answer (score 2):

**Using Calc**

If You wanted to set the width of only a single element, you may want to look at the `calc()` option.

Something like:

```
width: calc(100% - width px);
```

in which could be incorporated into most projects nowadays, as you can see from its [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

---

You could also make use of the `auto` width:

```
.secondElement{
  width:auto;
}
```

to fill the space left

---

Have a look here...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
input {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.fix {
  border: none;
  background: gray;
}
.now {
  width: 49.5%;
}
.nowNew {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Div on left</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="text here" />

<br/>Notice the lengths aren't the same? Yet both are defined as 50%?
<br/><br/>
<br/>That's due to the border around the input!
<br/><br/><br/>

<div>Div on left</div><input class="fix" type="text" placeholder="text here" />

<br/><br/>
<br/>To fix 'stuff' like this, I feel the general rule in web dev. is to aim to make it 99.9% instead:
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="now">Div on left</div><input class="now" type="text" placeholder="text here" />

<br/><br/>
<br/>Or make the input width auto:
<br/><br/><br/>
<div>Div on left</div>
<input class="nowNew" type="text" placeholder="text here" />
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/vywfazue/ we can also use `box-sizing:border-box` instead of removing borders :) +1

Comment: I got the impression from the question that the OP didn't want to set a width on the input element (i.e. it should fill the available space)

Comment: @JRulle: I hadn't *actually* finished editing my answer. (*As you can probably see with my constant edits*). But there's still a few options.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/1516/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <input type="textbox" value="right" id="right" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 180px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: quite different answer: nice +1

Comment: thanks @NaeemShaikh, just playing into the fact that table-cells stretch to fill the available space (which is coincidentally the OPs goal).