# Webpage boxes in a horizontal row

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is create 2 or more text boxes, side by side rather than stacked vertically.

I have tried using floats, which is fine for 2 boxes side by side, but isn't good for 3. Also, floats make the page look messy on mobile.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: css - display: inline;, sorry missed the mobile - heres an example though http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html .For responsive sites bootstrap or something like that is a good choice

Comment: You have to use media queries to achieve different results on the multiple devices

Comment: [My answer to something very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27945920/3436942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `display: inline-block` but you should also use Media Queries to adjust the width of the inline boxes depending on the screen size of the device reading the page.

You can also use a framework such as Twitter Bootstrap which has a build in responsive framework based on a grid system.

Answer (score 0):

You might even don't media queries:

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/vc8grd4u/)

```
.box {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 180px;
       height: 180px;
       background: #ddd;
     }
```

And [**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2vbetnq/) with floats.

And just the size of result window: what's wrong with it? What is currently not working properly and what are you trying to achieve (both on desktop and mobile)?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box-container{
  display:inline-block;
  width:450px;
  }
.box{
  display:block;
  width:33%;
  float:left;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  margin-left:0.3%;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="box">box</div>
</div>
```